# C++ Hamming Function

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading, hamming-distance

This program is supposed to create three arrays of class object My_array. The first array is filled with random numbers. The second array is an exact copy of the first. The third array is entered by the user. The program checks to make sure that the first two arrays indeed equal each other and then it check to the hamming distance of the first and third array. The professor defines the hamming distance as each part off the array that is different.

My problem has been getting hamming to work. I actually have a hard time with operating overloading so I am surprised that works (well I have no errors showing in VS Studio) but not the hamming part. Any help would be appreciated. There are three files in order: `main.cpp`, `my_array.cpp`, and `my_array.h`. Function definitions and declarations were provided by professor. I am required to insert how each function operates.

```
#include "my_array.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;

    cout << "How big of an array shall we work with? ";
    cin >> size;
    My_array a(size);                       
    My_array b(size);
    My_array c(size);

    a.randomize(100);                           

    b = a;

    c.input();


    cout << a << endl;                            
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << c << endl;

    cout << "a != b: " << (a != b) << endl;
    cout << "a == b: " << (a == b) << endl;
    cout << "The hamming distance is: " << a.hamming(c);


    return 0;
}



#include "my_array.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


// Constructor
My_array::My_array(int the_size)
{
    array = NULL;
    size = 0;
    resize(the_size);
}

// Destructor.
My_array::~My_array()
{
    empty();
}

// Copy constructor
My_array::My_array(My_array &data)
    : size(data.size)
{
    array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = data.array[i];
}

// Overloaded assignment operator.
My_array &My_array::operator=(My_array &data)
{
    if (this != &data) {
        resize(data.size);
        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            array[i] = data.array[i];
    }
    else
        cout << "Attempt to copy an object on itself. "
        << "Operation ignored." << endl;
    return *this;
}

void My_array::input()
{
    int j;
    cout << "Please enter " << size << " numbers.\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> j;
        array[i] = j;
    }
}

void My_array::randomize(int limit)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % limit + 1;
}

bool My_array::operator ==(My_array &data)
{
    if(this->size != data.size)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
    {
        if (*this[i].array != data.array[i])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool My_array::operator !=(My_array &data)
{
    if (*this == data)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int My_array::hamming(My_array &data)
{
    int ham = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (*this[i].array != data[i].array)
            ham++;
    return ham;
}

// This function will empty the target object
void My_array::empty()
{
    if (size != 0 && array != NULL) {
        size = 0;
        delete[] array;
    }
}

// Resize the array.
void My_array::resize(int the_size)
{
    if (size >= 0) {
        empty();
        if (the_size != 0) {
            size = the_size;
            array = new int[size];
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Resize attepmted with a negative size. "
        << "Operation ignored." << endl;
}

// Access an element of the array.
int &My_array::operator[](int index)
{
    if (index < size)
        return array[index];
    else {
        cerr << "Illegal access to an element of the array." << endl
            << "The size of the array was " << size
            << " and the index was " << index << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

// Accessor
int My_array::get_size()
{
    return size;
}

void My_array::output()
{
    cout << "The array of size " << size
        << " contains the elements:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        cout << array[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}

//overloading the << operator.
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, My_array &data)
{
    out << "The array of size " << data.size
        << " contains the elements:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<data.size; i++)
        out << data.array[i] << ' ';
    out << endl;
    return out;
}

#ifndef MY_ARRAY_H
#define MY_ARRAY_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class My_array {
protected:
    int size;                 
    int *array;               

public:
    // Constructor
    My_array(int the_size = 0);

// Destructor
~My_array();

// Copy constructor
My_array(My_array &data);

// Assignment operator
My_array &operator=(My_array &data);

void input();

void randomize(int limit);

bool operator ==(My_array &data);

bool operator !=(My_array &data);

int hamming(My_array &data);

// Deletes the array
void empty();

// Resize the array.
void resize(int the_size = 0);

// Access an element of the array.
int &operator[](int index);

// Returns the size of the array.
int get_size();

// Output the elements of the array.
void output();


friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, My_array &data);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you take a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section on [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); basically, you should strip your example down to the bare minimum -- with all necessary data -- before posting it. This is not just for our convenience (although that will give you solutions sooner), you're likely to spot the error yourself in the process of preparing a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
*this[i].array != data[i].array
```

should be this:

```
array[i] != data.array[i]
```

or this:

```
array[i] != data[i]
```

The `*this` is unnecessary, and `data[i]` is a reference to an `int` (the same one you get by calling `data.array[i]`, thanks to your `operator[]`), and an `int` has no member called "array".